# Two Button click event in single cell in TableView in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I am making custom cell in xamarin iOS. In the cell I have two Button which is display in the below figure.

**Figure :**

[image]

**Two Button are :**

1. Create Appointment
2. View Detail

I want to create this two different Button click Event in My Source class so that I can send data to different ViewController for my purpose.

**Code :** 
**TableCell class :**

```
public partial class CaseHistoryTableCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CaseHistoryTableCell");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;

        static CaseHistoryTableCell()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("CaseHistoryTableCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        public CaseHistoryTableCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public static CaseHistoryTableCell Create()
        {
            return (CaseHistoryTableCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }

        public void BindData(string hospitalLabel, string addressLabel, string drLabel, string patientLabel)
        {
            this.lbl_hospitalName.Text = hospitalLabel;
            this.lbl_address.Text = addressLabel;

            this.lbl_drName.Text = drLabel;
            this.lbl_patientName.Text = patientLabel;

            this.lbl_address.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_patientName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_caseDate.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_scheDate.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_hospitalName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);
            this.lbl_drName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);

            this.btn_createAppointment.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);
            this.btn_viewDetail.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);
        }

        public override CGRect Frame
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Frame;
            }

            set
            {
                value.Y += 4;
                value.Height -= 2 * 4;
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Source Class :**

```
public class CaseHistorySourceClass : UITableViewSource
        {
            private List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems;
            public CaseSearchItem caseSearchItem;
            public static event EventHandler RowClicked;

            public CaseHistorySourceClass(List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems)
            {
                this.caseSearchItems = caseSearchItems;
            }

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                CaseHistoryTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CaseHistoryTableCell.Key) as CaseHistoryTableCell ?? CaseHistoryTableCell.Create();
                var item = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];

                cell.BindData(item.Organization, item.Address, item.Doctor, item.UserName);

                cell.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
                cell.Layer.CornerRadius = 10.0f;
                cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                cell.SetNeedsLayout();
                cell.LayoutIfNeeded();
                return cell;
            }


            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
            {
                return caseSearchItems.Count;
            }
        }
```

**My Question :**

It is possible to Create two different Button click event in a single Cell.

If yes then How ?

and If No then what is alternative to Perform this type of operation.

> **Note :** I doesn't want to require `RowSelected`. I only require how to
>   perform this two different Button click Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding target action to button from your GetCell method:

first add following in your cell class to make buttons accessible:

```
public UIButton btnCreateAppointment { 

            get
            {
                return this.btn_createAppointment;
            }
        }


        public UIButton btnViewDetail 
        {

            get
            {
                return this.btn_viewDetail;
            }
        }
```

Now from modify your GetCell method to add action target

```
cell.btnCreateAppointment.tag = indexPath.Row;
cell.btnViewDetail.tag = indexPath.row;


//assign action
cell.btnCreateAppointment.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {
                 var row = ((UIButton)sender).Tag;
                 var item = caseSearchItems[row];

            };
 cell.btnViewDetail.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {
                 var row = ((UIButton)sender).Tag;
                 var item = caseSearchItems[row];

            };
```

Comment: It says `cell.btn_createAppointment.tag` is inaccessible for it's protection level.

Comment: Define property for btn_createAppointment in your cell.  I can see its not public member

Comment: Of if you already have property btnCreateAppointment and it accessible, Use cell.btnCreateAppointment instead.

Comment: Actually i new to iOS can you edit how to define that property.

Comment: Sure, Give me 2 min.

Comment: added code in answer for making button accessible. Please add that in you r CaseHistoryTableCell class

Comment: Is this right apporch or not `var row = ((UIButton)sender).Tag;`

Comment: see my upper comment code that work. you can edit your answer.

Comment: see the edit only this way it work. and once again Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do such operation on `RowSelected` 
Setting Target with selector will help you out .

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                CaseHistoryTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CaseHistoryTableCell.Key) as CaseHistoryTableCell ?? CaseHistoryTableCell.Create();
                var item = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];

// setTag to button to identify in which row button is pressed 
cell.btnCreateAppointment.tag=indexPath.Row;
cell.btnViewDetail.tag=indexPath.row;

// set Target to a method 
cell.btnCreateAppointment.TouchUpInside += createAppointment;
ell.btnViewDetail.TouchUpInside +=viewDetail;


            }
```

These Method will be called when Press you button

```
 public void createAppointment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var row=sender.tag;

}
```

Second button Clicked event

```
public void viewDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var row=sender.tag;

}
```

i hope this work.

Comment: Wait i try and come back to you soon.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15560/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-a-table-cell

please take a look at here .... how to put custom button &how to setup it's target..

Comment: Thanks that help me.